# Unwanted behavior of Chinese punctuation mark getting incorporated into the URL right before it

Tags: xetex, urls, xecjk

Minimal working example:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{標楷體}
\begin{document}
網址：http://www.google.com/。
\end{document}
```

When I open the pdf and click on the link, it brings me to `http://www.google.com/。`. I've tried putting the URL inside braces, but that doesn't restrict its scope. The problem goes away if I add a space between the URL and the Chinese period mark, but that extra space is not desirable and not easy to calculate and remove using `hspace`. Is there an easy fix without resorting to the `hyperref` package? I am asking this question out of curiosity and ignorance, and since I only include one or two URLs, I also think it is a bit overkill to add one more package just to solve this problem.

---

**EDIT**: None of the suggestions worked. I've tried all of the following, but on my SumatraPDF, the link still directs to `http://www.google.com/。`.

```
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
...
網址：http://www.google.com/?。
網址：http://www.google.com/\#。
網址：http://www.google.com/\hspace{1pt}。
網址：http://www.google.com/\vphantom{0}。
網址：\tt{http://www.google.com/}。 % @Symbol1 Is this what you mean by do the formatting myself?
網址：\href{http://www.google.com/}{http://www.google.com/}。 % Works without the `draft` option.
```

I guess I'll just stick to using the full `hyperref` package. Not a big deal, really.

Comment: Without the hyperref package it isn't really a link. Depending on your viewer it might try to automatically find links, with different correctness. So if you don't want to include it is a real link, it is really a viewer problem. Also if it is linked or not and what part of it will depend heavily on the viewer used.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Workaround to a zeoth approximation is to add a `#` to the end of your link, as in many many cases, referencing a non-existing fragment of the page is not harmful.

Comment: @JuriRobl What about with the `url` package? Does it only do formatting and not make it a link? I use the SumatraPDF viewer.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I also can't compile and receive the error message "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode."

Comment: @GaoWeiwei No, the `url` package only handles the typesetting (typewriter-font and linebreaks), not the linking. If you want to typeset `#` you need to escape it: `\#`

Comment: If your PDF viewer ignore `?` in URLs, please delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- use the *lite* version `\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}`
- add a question mark after a link `網址：http://www.google.com/?。`
- add some invalid unicode character or special characters like [zero width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).
- do the formatting your self. (why not? just two)